# The instruction at 0x00007FF697F8AE43 referenced memory at OxFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF. The memory could not be read

Tags: c++, c++14

I'm writing a programming lab and I have this error, I don't know how to solve this, please help
[bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpGdK.png)
the program crashes when I select item 10 and information from the file is not deleted afterward

Also, the program  doesn't delete information from file

My mentor said that I must delete string and write cod without them, but tasks if the lab require to use string

help me, please

there is my code

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

const int MAX_LENGTH = 100;

using namespace std;

enum Options {
    EXIT,
    GET_COUNT,
    GET_DRIVERS,
    GET_ADDRESSES,
    SET_DRIVERS,
    SET_ADDRESSES,
    INPUT,
    OUTPUT,
    FILE_OUTPUT,
    FILE_INPUT,
    PRINT_FILE,
    FREE_TAKEN_RATIO,
    DRIVER_BY_ADDRESS,
    HAS_DRIVER_ADDRESS,
    CHECK_COPY_TAXI,
    CHECK_DYNAMIC_TAXI
};

class Taxi {
    int drivers[MAX_LENGTH];   // Масив водіїв
    int driversLength;
    static int count;          // Статичне поле для відстеження кількості таксі

protected:
    string addresses[MAX_LENGTH];
    int addressesLength;

public:
    string passenger;                   // Пасажир
    Taxi();                              // Конструктори
    Taxi(int*, int, string*, int, string);
    Taxi(Taxi&);
    ~Taxi();                      // Деструктор
    void getDrivers();           // Методи для отримання і встановлення даних про водіїв та адреси
    void getAddresses();
    void setDrivers(int*, int);
    void setAddresses(string*, int);
    void input();
    void output();
    void fileOutput(string);
    void fileInput(string);
    bool order(int, string);
    int order(string);
    double order();
    static int getCount() { return count; }// Статичний метод для отримання кількості таксі
};

int getNumber(string);
void fillArrayOfDrivers(int*, int);
void fillArrayOfAddresses(string*, int);
void fileOutputAll(string);
void checkCopyTaxi(Taxi&);
void checkDynamicTaxi();
int menu();

bool Taxi::order(int id, string addr) {
    if (drivers[id] == 1)
        return true;
    return false;
}

int Taxi::order(string addr) {
    for (int i = 0; i < driversLength; i++)
        if (drivers[i] == 1) {
            drivers[i] = 0;
            return i + 1;
        }
    return 0;
}

double Taxi::order() {
    int free = 0;
    int taken = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < driversLength; i++)
        if (drivers[i])
            free++;
        else
            taken++;

    if (taken == 0)
        return -1;
    else
        return (double)free / taken;
}
// Оголошення статичної змінної
int Taxi::count = 0;

// Опис конструкторів та деструктора
Taxi::Taxi() {
    driversLength = 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < driversLength; i++)
        drivers[i] = 1;

    addressesLength = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < addressesLength; i++)
        addresses[i] = "street123";

    passenger = "Johnny";
    cout << "Taxi by default is created!\n";
    count++;
}

Taxi::Taxi(int* dr, int drLength, string* addr, int addrLength, string pas) {

    driversLength = drLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < driversLength; i++)
        drivers[i] = dr[i];

    addressesLength = addrLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < addressesLength; i++)
        addresses[i] = addr[i];

    passenger = pas;
    cout << "Taxi by parameters is created!\n";
    count++;
}

Taxi::Taxi(Taxi& t) {
    driversLength = t.driversLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < driversLength; i++)
        drivers[i] = t.drivers[i];

    addressesLength = t.addressesLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < t.addressesLength; i++)
        addresses[i] = t.addresses[i];

    passenger = t.passenger;
    cout << "Taxi by copy is created!\n";
    count++;
}

Taxi::~Taxi() {
    cout << "Taxi is now deleted!\n";
    count--;
}


void Taxi::input() {
    driversLength = getNumber("Enter drivers length: ");
    fillArrayOfDrivers(drivers, driversLength);

    addressesLength = getNumber("Enter addresses length: ");
    fillArrayOfAddresses(addresses, addressesLength);

    cout << "Enter passenger name: ";
    getline(cin, passenger);
    cout << "\n";
}

void Taxi::output() {
    cout << "Drivers: " << setw(22) << "Addresses: " << setw(22)
        << "Passenger: " << endl;
    int i = 0;
    while ((i < addressesLength && i < driversLength) || i == 0) {
        if (drivers[i] == 1)
            cout << "Driver " << i + 1 << " is free";
        else
            cout << "Driver " << i + 1 << " is taken";

        cout << setw(15) << addresses[i];

        if (i == 0)
            cout << setw(15) << passenger;
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }

    while (i < driversLength) {
        if (drivers[i] == 1)
            cout << "Driver " << i + 1 << " is free\n";
        else
            cout << "Driver " << i + 1 << " is taken\n";
        i++;
    }

    while (i < addressesLength) {
        cout << setw(31) << addresses[i] << "\n";
        i++;
    }
}

int getNumber(string msg) {// Функція для отримання числа від користувача
    cout << msg;
    char number[11];
    cin.getline(number, 11);
    return atoi(number);
}

void fillArrayOfDrivers(int* array, int length) {// Функція для заповнення масиву водіїв
    if (length == 0)
        return;
    cout << "Enter drivers: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        char answer;
        cout << "Is driver " << i + 1 << " free?(y/n) ";
        cin >> answer;
        if (answer == 'y')
            array[i] = 1;
        else
            array[i] = 0;
    }
    cin.ignore();
    cout << "\n";
}

void fillArrayOfAddresses(string* array, int length) {
    if (length == 0)
        return;
    cout << "Enter addresses: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        cout << "Enter address " << i + 1 << ": ";
        getline(cin, array[i]);
    }
    cout << "\n";
}

void checkCopyTaxi(Taxi& chosenTaxi) {// Функція для перевірки роботи програми з копією таксі
    Taxi copyTaxi = chosenTaxi;
    int dr[MAX_LENGTH];
    string addr[MAX_LENGTH];
    int addrLength, drLength, count;

    double ratio;
    int driverId, chosenDriverId;
    string chosenAddress;
    string filename;

    cout << "Set drivers of copy taxi: \n";
    drLength = getNumber("Enter drivers length: ");
    fillArrayOfDrivers(dr, drLength);
    copyTaxi.setDrivers(dr, drLength);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Set addresses of copy taxi: \n";
    addrLength = getNumber("Enter addresses length: ");
    fillArrayOfAddresses(addr, addrLength);
    copyTaxi.setAddresses(addr, addrLength);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Get drivers of copy taxi: \n";
    copyTaxi.getDrivers();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Get addresses of copy taxi: \n";
    copyTaxi.getAddresses();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Input copy taxi: \n";
    copyTaxi.input();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Output copy taxi: \n";
    copyTaxi.output();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Output copy taxi to file: \n";
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    copyTaxi.fileOutput(filename);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Input copy taxi from file: \n";
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    copyTaxi.fileInput(filename);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Get free/taken ratio for copy taxi: \n";
    ratio = copyTaxi.order();
    if (ratio == -1)
        cout << "All drivers are free" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Free/taken ratio: " << ratio << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Get driver by address for copy taxi: \n";
    cout << "Enter an address: ";
    getline(cin, chosenAddress);
    driverId = copyTaxi.order(chosenAddress);
    if (!driverId)
        cout << "No drivers by address " << chosenAddress << endl;
    else
        cout << "Driver's id: " << driverId << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Check if chosen driver with chosen address is free for copy "
        "taxi: \n";
    chosenDriverId = getNumber("Enter id of chosen driver: ");
    cout << "Enter an address: ";
    getline(cin, chosenAddress);
    if (copyTaxi.order(chosenDriverId, chosenAddress))
        cout << "Driver " << chosenDriverId << " with address " << chosenAddress
        << " is free\n";
    else
        cout << "Driver " << chosenDriverId << " with address " << chosenAddress
        << " is taken/not found\n";
    cout << endl;
}

void checkDynamicTaxi() { // Функція для перевірки роботи програми з динамічно створеним таксі
    Taxi* dynamicTaxi = new Taxi;
    int dr[MAX_LENGTH];
    string addr[MAX_LENGTH];
    int addrLength, drLength, count;

    double ratio;
    int driverId, chosenDriverId;
    string chosenAddress;
    string filename;

    cout << "Set drivers of dynamically created taxi: \n";
    drLength = getNumber("Enter drivers length: ");
    fillArrayOfDrivers(dr, drLength);
    dynamicTaxi->setDrivers(dr, drLength);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Set addresses of dynamically created taxi: \n";
    addrLength = getNumber("Enter addresses length: ");
    fillArrayOfAddresses(addr, addrLength);
    dynamicTaxi->setAddresses(addr, addrLength);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Get drivers of dynamically created taxi: \n";
    dynamicTaxi->getDrivers();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Get addresses of dynamically created taxi: \n";
    dynamicTaxi->getAddresses();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Input dynamically created taxi: \n";
    dynamicTaxi->input();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Output dynamically created taxi: \n";
    dynamicTaxi->output();
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Output dynamically created taxi to file: \n";
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    dynamicTaxi->fileOutput(filename);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Input dynamically created taxi from file: \n";
    cout << "Enter filename: ";
    getline(cin, filename);
    dynamicTaxi->fileInput(filename);
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Get free/taken ratio for dynamically created taxi: \n";
    ratio = dynamicTaxi->order();
    if (ratio == -1)
        cout << "All drivers are free" << endl;
    else
        cout << "Free/taken ratio: " << ratio << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Get driver by address for dynamically created taxi: \n";
    cout << "Enter an address: ";
    getline(cin, chosenAddress);
    driverId = dynamicTaxi->order(chosenAddress);
    if (!driverId)
        cout << "No drivers by address " << chosenAddress << endl;
    else
        cout << "Driver's id: " << driverId << endl;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Check if chosen driver with chosen address is free for dynamically "
        "created "
        "taxi: \n";

    chosenDriverId = getNumber("Enter id of chosen driver: ");
    cout << "Enter an address: ";
    getline(cin, chosenAddress);
    if (dynamicTaxi->order(chosenDriverId, chosenAddress))
        cout << "Driver " << chosenDriverId << " with address " << chosenAddress
        << " is free\n";
    else
        cout << "Driver " << chosenDriverId << " with address " << chosenAddress
        << " is taken/not found\n";
    cout << endl;

    delete dynamicTaxi;
}

int menu() {
    cout << "\n"
        << EXIT << ") Exit\n"
        << GET_COUNT << ") Get count\n"
        << GET_DRIVERS << ") Get drivers\n"
        << GET_ADDRESSES << ") Get addresses\n"
        << SET_DRIVERS << ") Set drivers\n"
        << SET_ADDRESSES << ") Set addresses\n"
        << INPUT << ") Input new taxi\n"
        << OUTPUT << ") Output taxi\n"
        << FILE_OUTPUT << ") Output taxi to file\n"
        << FILE_INPUT << ") Input taxi from file\n"
        << PRINT_FILE << ") Print contents of file\n"
        << FREE_TAKEN_RATIO << ") Get free/taken ratio\n"
        << DRIVER_BY_ADDRESS << ") Get driver by address\n"
        << HAS_DRIVER_ADDRESS
        << ") Check if chosen driver with chosen address is free\n"
        << CHECK_COPY_TAXI << ") Check if program works with copy taxi\n"
        << CHECK_DYNAMIC_TAXI << ") Check if program works with dynamic taxi\n";

    int option = getNumber("What option? ");
    cout << "\n";
    return option;
}

void Taxi::getDrivers() {// Метод для виведення водіїв таксі
    if (driversLength == 0) {
        cout << "This taxi does not have any drivers yet\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "Drivers: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < driversLength; i++)
        if (drivers[i] == 1)
            cout << "Driver " << i << " is free\n";
        else
            cout << "Driver " << i << " is taken\n";
}

void Taxi::getAddresses() {// Метод для виведення адрес таксі
    if (addressesLength == 0) {
        cout << "This taxi does not have any addresses yet\n";
        return;
    }
    cout << "Addresses: \n";
    for (int i = 0; i < addressesLength; i++)
        cout << addresses[i] << endl;
}

void Taxi::setDrivers(int* dr, int drLength) { // Метод для встановлення водіїв таксі
    driversLength = drLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < driversLength; i++)
        drivers[i] = dr[i];

    cout << "Drivers are set!\n";
}

void Taxi::setAddresses(string* addr, int addrLength) { // Метод для встановлення адрес таксі
    addressesLength = addrLength;
    for (int i = 0; i < addressesLength; i++)
        addresses[i] = addr[i];
    cout << "Adddresses are set!\n";
}

void Taxi::fileInput(string filename) {// Метод для введення даних таксі з файлу
    ifstream fileRead(filename, ios::binary);
    if (!fileRead.is_open()) {
        cout << "Cannot open " << filename << endl;
        return;
    }

    fileRead.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int fileSize = fileRead.tellg();
    if (fileSize == 0) {
        cout << filename << " is empty\n";
        fileRead.close();
        return;
    }

    fileRead.seekg(fileSize - sizeof(*this), ios::beg);
    fileRead.read((char*)this, sizeof(*this));

    cout << "Taxi is succesfully inputted from " << filename << "\n";
    fileRead.close();
}

void Taxi::fileOutput(string filename) {// Метод для виведення даних таксі у файл
    ofstream fileWrite(filename, ios::app | ios::binary);
    if (!fileWrite.is_open()) {
        cout << "Cannot open " << filename << " for an output\n";
        return;
    }

    fileWrite.write((char*)this, sizeof(*this));
    cout << "Taxi is succesfully outputted to " << filename << "\n";
    fileWrite.close();
}

void fileOutputAll(string filename) { // Функція для виведення всіх таксі з файлу
    ifstream fileRead(filename, ios::binary);
    if (!fileRead.is_open()) {
        cout << "Cannot open " << filename << endl;
        return;
    }

    fileRead.seekg(0, ios::end);
    int fileSize = fileRead.tellg();
    if (fileSize == 0) {
        cout << filename << " is empty\n";
        fileRead.close();
        return;
    }
    fileRead.seekg(0, ios::beg);
    while (!fileRead.eof()) {
        Taxi myTaxi;
        fileRead.read((char*)&myTaxi, sizeof(myTaxi));
        //myTaxi.output();
        cout << endl;
    }
    fileRead.close();
    cout << "finish";
}



int main() {
    cout << "Count: " << Taxi::getCount() << endl;
    Taxi chosenTaxi;
    int dr[MAX_LENGTH];
    string addr[MAX_LENGTH];
    int addrLength, drLength, count;

    double ratio;
    int driverId, chosenDriverId;
    string chosenAddress;
    string filename;

    int option;
    do {
        option = menu();
        switch (option) {
        case GET_COUNT:
            count = Taxi::getCount();
            cout << "Count: " << count << endl;
            break;
        case GET_DRIVERS:
            chosenTaxi.getDrivers();
            break;
        case GET_ADDRESSES:
            chosenTaxi.getAddresses();
            break;
        case SET_DRIVERS:
            drLength = getNumber("Enter drivers length: ");
            fillArrayOfDrivers(dr, drLength);
            chosenTaxi.setDrivers(dr, drLength);
            break;
        case SET_ADDRESSES:
            addrLength = getNumber("Enter addresses length: ");
            fillArrayOfAddresses(addr, addrLength);
            chosenTaxi.setAddresses(addr, addrLength);
            break;
        case INPUT:
            chosenTaxi.input();
            break;
        case OUTPUT:
            cout << "Chosen taxi: \n";
            chosenTaxi.output();
            break;
        case FILE_OUTPUT:
            cout << "Enter filename: ";
            getline(cin, filename);
            chosenTaxi.fileOutput(filename);
            break;
        case FILE_INPUT:
            cout << "Enter filename: ";
            getline(cin, filename);
            chosenTaxi.fileInput(filename);
            break;
        case PRINT_FILE:
            cout << "Enter filename: ";
            getline(cin, filename);
            fileOutputAll(filename);
            break;
        case FREE_TAKEN_RATIO:
            ratio = chosenTaxi.order();
            if (ratio == -1)
                cout << "All drivers are free" << endl;
            else
                cout << "Free/taken ratio: " << ratio << endl;
            break;
        case DRIVER_BY_ADDRESS:
            cout << "Enter an address: ";
            getline(cin, chosenAddress);
            driverId = chosenTaxi.order(chosenAddress);
            if (!driverId)
                cout << "No drivers by address " << chosenAddress << endl;
            else
                cout << "Driver's id: " << driverId << endl;
            break;
        case HAS_DRIVER_ADDRESS:
            chosenDriverId = getNumber("Enter id of chosen driver: ");
            cout << "Enter an address: ";
            getline(cin, chosenAddress);
            if (chosenTaxi.order(chosenDriverId, chosenAddress))
                cout << "Driver " << chosenDriverId << " with address " << chosenAddress
                << " is free\n";
            else
                cout << "Driver " << chosenDriverId << " with address " << chosenAddress
                << " is taken/not found\n";
            break;

        case CHECK_COPY_TAXI:
            checkCopyTaxi(chosenTaxi);
            break;
        case CHECK_DYNAMIC_TAXI:
            checkDynamicTaxi();
            break;
        case EXIT:
            cout << "End of program\n\n";
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Choose valid option\n";
            break;
        }
    } while (option != EXIT);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Run it in a debugger; that will tell you where it crashes. Then, look at that line and think about where the invalid pointer came from.

Comment: `fileRead.read((char*)this, sizeof(*this));` won't work; that's not how to serialize a non-POD class.  Also, turn on compiler warnings.  Fix warnings.  Does that make the bug go away?